# Bash - get empty array in return on macOS

Tags: arrays, bash, macos, terminal

With regards to this question ([Put line seperated grep result into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611729/put-line-seperated-grep-result-into-array)), when I use

```
echo v1.33.4 | arr=($(egrep -o '[0-9]{1,3}'))
```

with `GNU bash, version 5.0.2(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0)` on `macOS`

I get have an empty array `arr` in return for

```
echo "($arr)"
()
```

then the expected output

```
1
33
4
```

What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't work with the syntax you have. You are *not* populating the array with the result of `grep`. You are not handling the string passed over the pipe and populating an empty array at the received end of the pipe.

Perhaps you were intending to do

```
array=($(echo v1.33.4 | egrep -o '[0-9]{1,3}'))
```

Notice how the `echo` of the string is passed over to the standard input of `egrep` which was missing in your attempt.

But as in the linked answer, using `mapfile` would be the best option here because with the above approach if the search results contains words containing spaces, they would be stored in separated indices in the array rather than in a single one.

```
mapfile -t array < <(echo "v1.33.4" |  egrep -o '[0-9]{1,3}')
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

Notice the array expansion in `bash` takes the syntax of `"${array[@]}"` and not just a simple `"${array}"` expansion.

Comment: Hi Inian, thank you very much. It functions. Do you know how to populate the array in more sophisticated command like in my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137242/bash-get-a-list-of-dates-for-every-saturday-on-a-given-year

Answer (score 1):

Messed with it a bit and this seems to work:

```
$ arr=$(echo "v1.33.4" |  egrep -o '[0-9]{1,3}')
$ echo $arr
1 33 4
$ echo "($arr)"
(1
33
4)
```

Comment: Thank you, Brian, for your answer!